# How to execute a Python statement on the JavaFX application thread in the interactive console?

Tags: python, multithreading, javafx, jython

I am developing a JavaFX application in Jython.  I often start `jython` with `-i` to get an interactive console, so I can execute Python statements to inspect/stimulate my application.  However, I often forget that such statements are not executed on the JavaFX application thread, so I am answered with:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = MainThread
```

So, I came up with this:

```
import java.lang.Runnable
import javafx.application.Platform

def runOnJavaFXApplicationThread(func):

    class _Runnable(java.lang.Runanble):

        def __init__(self, func):
            self.func = func

        def run(self):
            self.func()

    javafx.application.Platform.runLater(_Runnable(func))
```

Which allows me to do this:

```
>>> runOnJavaFXApplicationThread(lambda: someStatement())
```

However, this hardly satisfies.  I have to remember to import the module that contains this function and to wrap everything in `runOnJavaFXApplicationThread(lambda:` and `)`.  This is really annoying when I want to execute several statements.

To execute several statements, I would like to be able to say this:

```
>>> runOnJavaFXApplicationThread('''
someStatement()
anotherStatement()
yetAnotherStatement()''')
```

How would I accomplish that?

Or, does the Python (Jython) console have the means to 'filter' the commands you give it through some function?